# ASP.NET Core 2.0 URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing a large ASP.NET Core 2 web application but I still get confused with URLs.

When fist learning, I thought URL's took on the name of the View, but discovered they come from the Controller method.

Here is an example to convey my issue:

I have a controller method named **Daysheet**, which returns a view and model with the same name.

In the Daysheet view, I call various controller methods from Javascript to perform specific actions. One of them is called **AssignStaff** which takes two integer parameters.

In the AssignStaff method I again return the Daysheet view with model, but now my URL is "AssignStaff"!

I can't just do a redirect because the whole Daysheet model is not being passed to the AssignStaff method.

I have many situations like this where after calling an action, I end up with another URL that I don't want.

**UPDATE/EDIT**

Thanks for assistance and apologies if my explanation is confusing. I simply have a view called **Daysheet** that uses a model. I want to call various controller methods to perform various actions, but I want to stay on the "Daysheet" view/URL.

As mentioned, I can't just redirect because in the action method I no longer have the whole model from the **Daysheet** view. Also, if I redirect I can't pass the whole model because that causes an error saying the header is too long. I think my only choice may be to use ajax for the actions so that the URL doesn't change.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking (and you have not shown any code to explain). If you are making a redirect to `AssignStaff` then that will be the url (that is how the web works). If you want to stay on the same page, then use ajax to call your server methods

Comment: I think this has less to do about ASP.NET Core specifically, and more ASP.NET in general. In this case, it would be good to have a read of any MSDN articles regarding routing.

Comment: why do users down-vote my question? If I had all the answers I wouldn't be asking for assistance.

Comment: @RossKelly : sometimes people don't like questions being asked with little to no explanation or examples, as was initially the case. Unfortunately, instead of asking for more information, they use the downvote as a signal for the quality of the question/description. Some of those users don't even know the problem domain, and still downvote! I don't think its fair, other people at least ask for more information. So: don't let it get you down :-).

Comment: @RobBos thanks for your comment. i'll try to make my questions/explanations clearer and more descriptive. i have Parkinsons, so sometimes it gets difficult to type.

Answer (score 3):

When you just do Return View("") name in a Controller Action, the URL will be the name of the Action you are using.

If you want to redirect to some specific Action, that will help to make sure the Url matches to where you are. You might want to read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

To do so, use:

```
RedirectToAction()
```

Answer (score 0):

The URLs your application responds to are called "routes", and they are either created by convention or explicitly. The default is by convention, of course, which is a URL in the form of `/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}`. `Index` is the default action if that portion of the route is left off, so a request to `/foo` will by convention map to `FooController.Index`. `HomeController` is the default controller, so an empty path (e.g. http://sample.com) will by convention invoke `HomeController.Index`.

Razor Pages have their own conventions. These do somewhat follow the file system, but exclude the `Pages` part of the path. So a Razor Page like `Pages/Foo/MyRazorPage.cshtml`, will load up under `/Foo/MyRazorPage`.

There there is the `Route` attribute, which allows you to specify a totally custom route. This attribute can be applied to a controller class and individual actions in the class. For example:

```
[Route("foo")]
public class MyAwesomeController
{
    [Route("bar")]
    public IActionResult MyAwesomeAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

With that, a request to `/foo/bar` will actually invoke `MyAwesomeController.MyAwesomeAction`.